# discord.py kicking specific user by message on channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been making discord bot for me and my friends.
I'd like to make everyone on our server (regardless of their ranks) able to kick specific person.
Let his name be George

that's George:

```
George = {
'id' : '123456789',
'username' : 'george12'
}
```

I was trying to make it in this way:

```
if message.content.startswith("Goodbay George"):
   await george['id'].kick
```

and this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
  await member.kick(reason = reason)


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

   if message.content.startswith("Goodbay George"):
      await kick(george['id'])      ### im not sure how provide member as argument, I got kick function from this forum
```

But None of this options works.
How can I make that what I'm expecting ? (told at the begining)

Comment: Have you tried to get the george object from the discord api ? It looks like your george is a `dict` which can't use `discord.Member` methods.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the `id` key from the `george` dict, you're getting a string (the ID of George), to actually kick someone it must be a `discord.Member` instance, to get it you can use `Guild.get_member` (this takes an integer)

```py
if message.content.startswith("Goodbay George"):
    george_id = int(george['id']) # already casting to an integer
    member = message.guild.get_member(george_id)
    await member.kick()
```

#### References:

- [`Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)
- [`Member.kick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.kick)

Comment: get_member   guild doesn't work 
``` 
member = message.guild.get_member(george_id)
```
have u got any other idea ?

Comment: Have you enabled `intents.members`?

Comment: I have. By using
 ```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
 intents.members = True
``` 
and in discord bot panel. The problem still exist.

Comment: When i have mu mouse cursor on ```member = message.guild.get_member(george_id) ``` I can see "[pyflakes] invalid syntax"

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly and that the it's a valid ID? The code above works flawlessly for me.

Comment: i copied your code 1 more time, invalid syntax error disapeared, but now i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kick'

Comment: Then the ID is invalid